# Remove array([]) brackets to create clean array for matrix equations

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, scikit-learn, vectorization

I want to remove array brackets from my vectors so I can turn them into matrices for equations, what is the best way to do this? I want the vector to be [0,0] instead of array([0,0]) so conjoined into matrices are [[0,0],[0,1]] instead of [array([0,0]) , array([0,1])]

my code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


#create all actual subject matters 
subjectmatters = ["basic", "python", "programming", "engineering", "mathematics", "logic", "hard", "html", "computers",
                  "design", "easy", "americanhistory", "history", "civilizations", "languagearts", "algebra",
                  "basicmath", "calculus", "nueralnets"]

#vectorize the subjects
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
subjectmatters_vectorized = vectorizer.fit_transform(subjectmatters)
subjectmatters_vectorized_to_array = subjectmatters_vectorized.toarray()
subjectmatters_vectorized_to_array_shape = np.shape(subjectmatters_vectorized.toarray())
subjectvectordict = dict(zip(subjectmatters, subjectmatters_vectorized_to_array))
print(subjectvectordict)
```

This prints the below, looking to have array[()] removed:

```
{
    "basic": array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "python": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]),
    "programming": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]),
    "engineering": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "mathematics": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]),
    "logic": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "hard": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "html": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "computers": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "design": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "easy": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "americanhistory": array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "history": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "civilizations": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "languagearts": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "algebra": array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "basicmath": array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "calculus": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
    "nueralnets": array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]),
}
```

Comment: Do you want dics values returned as lists?

Comment: I use the dictionary later on to create a matrix with the following code: basicpythoncourse1 = [subjectvectordict['basic'], subjectvectordict['python'], subjectvectordict['programming'], subjectvectordict['engineering'], subjectvectordict['mathematics'], subjectvectordict['logic']]  - I need the array brackets removed to preform an equation on this matrix

Comment: `list(array([...items...])) == [...items...]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see if this is what you want:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

#create all actual subject matters 
subjectmatters = ["basic", "python", "programming", "engineering", "mathematics", "logic", "hard", "html", "computers",
                  "design", "easy", "americanhistory", "history", "civilizations", "languagearts", "algebra",
                  "basicmath", "calculus", "nueralnets"]

#vectorize the subjects
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
subjectmatters_vectorized = vectorizer.fit_transform(subjectmatters)
subjectmatters_vectorized_to_array = subjectmatters_vectorized.toarray().tolist()

subjectvectordict = dict(zip(subjectmatters, subjectmatters_vectorized_to_array))
print(subjectvectordict)
{'basic': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],  
 'python': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],  
 'programming': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
 'engineering': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'mathematics': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 'logic': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'hard': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'html': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'computers': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'design': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'easy': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'americanhistory': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'history': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'civilizations': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'languagearts': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'algebra': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'basicmath': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'calculus': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 'nueralnets': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
 }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to do `.toarray()` before chaining `.tolist()`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I believe yes, sparse matrices do not have `.tolist()` method, neither `list(sparse_matrix)` works

Comment: please point out, in your answer, before anything else, the important difference between your code and the question's code: `.tolist()`